# Azure Communication services - video devices are not updated after disconnecting

Tags: angular, azure-communication-services

I have web application using ACS with page showing Local video preview. I listen on events "videoDevicesUpdated". When new USB camera is added, everything works fine, I'm notified about new camera, but when camera is disconnected during local video preview, I am not nofied about change. DeviceManager.getCameras() still returns disconnected camera even if I restart application. I have to close and restart browser (Chrome) to get correct list of cameras.